# ¿Cómo puedo poner textos encima de un corusel de boostrap?

Tags: html, bootstrap

Hace rato que estoy intentando poner ciertos textos encima de un carousel de boostrap y no he podido ¿Alguien tiene alguna solución para eso?

Comment: ¿de que versión de bootstrap estamos hablando y que código has puesto hasta el momento para intentarlo?

Comment: Por favor, edita la pregunta para limitarla a un problema específico con suficiente detalle para identificar una respuesta adecuada.

Answer (score 0):

En caso de que estes usando bootstrap 4, debes agregar una modificación al css de este modo para la clase **carousel-caption**:

```
.carousel-caption {
  top: 0;
  bottom: auto;
}
```

Dejo un snippet de ejemplo:

```css
.carousel-caption {
  top: 0;
  bottom: auto;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.0.0/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Gn5384xqQ1aoWXA+058RXPxPg6fy4IWvTNh0E263XmFcJlSAwiGgFAW/dAiS6JXm" crossorigin="anonymous">
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-KJ3o2DKtIkvYIK3UENzmM7KCkRr/rE9/Qpg6aAZGJwFDMVNA/GpGFF93hXpG5KkN" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/popper.js@1.12.9/dist/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-ApNbgh9B+Y1QKtv3Rn7W3mgPxhU9K/ScQsAP7hUibX39j7fakFPskvXusvfa0b4Q" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.0.0/dist/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-JZR6Spejh4U02d8jOt6vLEHfe/JQGiRRSQQxSfFWpi1MquVdAyjUar5+76PVCmYl" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<div class="container">
<h1>
Carousel
</h1>
<div id="carouselExampleSlidesOnly" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel">
  <div class="carousel-inner">
    <div class="carousel-item active">
      <img src="https://cdn.pixabay.com/photo/2015/04/23/22/00/tree-736885_960_720.jpg" alt="...">
      <div class="carousel-caption">
        <h5>Imagen bonita</h5>
        <p>Es una imagen bonita sacada de google images</p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
</div>
```